# How to change the way php returns the results of a sum with very small values

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array, sum

you will see maybe this problem sounds silly but it has tended me a bit stuck. 
You see, I have a function which receives an array, with this array a sum must be made, specifically sum one of its columns (I enter as the third parameter  of the function the column I want to sum).This work good. The problem is the way it generates the result. I show you my code:

```
function sumArray($array, $index, $col) {

    $returnArray = []; // temporary container

    // sanity checks
    if (!is_array($array)) {
        return 'error not an array';
    }

    $firstRow = reset($array);

    if (!array_key_exists($index, $firstRow) || !array_key_exists($col, $firstRow)) {
        return 'error keys provided not found';
    }
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        if (!isset($returnArray[$value[$index]])) { // initialize

            $returnArray[$value[$index]] = [$index => $value[$index], $col => 0];
        }
        // add value
        $returnArray[$value[$index]][$col] += $value[$col]; //here is the sum
    }

    return $returnArray;
}

$products = array ( //this is the array
    array("Id" => "000001", 
          "Name" => "Cheese", 
          "Quantity" => "0.00000012", 
          "Price" => "10"),

    array("Id" => "000001", 
          "Name" => "Cheese", 
          "Quantity" => "0.00000123", 
          "Price" => "20"),

    array("Id" => "000001", 
          "Name" => "Cheese", 
          "Quantity" => "0.00000020", 
          "Price" => "30"),

    array("Id" => "000002", 
          "Name" => "Ham", 
          "Quantity" => "0.00000346", 
          "Price" => "200"),

    array("Id" => "000002", 
          "Name" => "Ham", 
          "Quantity" => "0.000000998", 
          "Price" => "100"),

    array("Id" => "000003", 
          "Name" => "Baicon", 
          "Quantity" => "0.000000492", 
          "Price" => "900")
    );

$summedArray = sumArray($products, 'Name', 'Quantity');

print_r($summedArray);
```

the result of my sum is a new array. But look at the Quantity column:

```
Array ( 
    [Cheese] => Array ( [Name] => Cheese [Quantity] => 1.55E-6 ) 
    [Ham] => Array ( [Name] => Ham [Quantity] => 4.458E-6 ) 
    [Baicon] => Array ( [Name] => Baicon [Quantity] => 4.92E-7 ) 
)
```

This form: `4.458E-6` I don't like. I would like something like this: `0.000004458`

Do you know what I could do to get something like that? A suggestion would be of great help.

Comment: The value is a number, that's just how `print_r()` prints it. It uses exponential notation for very small fractions.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't really related to the fact that it's a sum. That's just the default string representation of a small float in PHP. Try this, for example:

```
$number = 0.000004458;
echo $number;             // displays 4.458E-6
```

The only reason the appearance changes in your output is that those values are strings in your input array, but when you add them together they are converted to floats.

If you want those values to display differently, you'll need to use some kind of formatting function that returns a string.

Assuming you aren't going to be using `print_r` to display the value in your final product, you can use `number_format` or `printf` to display it with however many decimal points you'd like.

```
foreach ($summedArray as $product => $info) {
    echo number_format($info['Quantity'], 9) . PHP_EOL;
    // or printf('%.9f', $info['Quantity']) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Great! I´m gonna prove it.